# Updating/overwriting a file in c without creating a new or temp file

Tags: c, file-handling

I am writing a c code for a file handling which have a file format such as below:

---

```
Domain1:IP:Port:Id1,Id2,Id3
Domain2:IP:Port:Id1,Id2,
```

---

It should be possible to add new line with new domains and also it should be possible to modify existing domains ID's. And with modify ID's I mean, the number of ID's can be increased or decreased such as in one operation I should be able to add ID4 to Domain1 in above example and also in another operation I should be able to delete ID1 of Domain2 as an example.

So my questions (thanks for help):

1. I don't want to create a temp/new file and change name and delete old file. So can I read and write to the existing file? How can make it secure? (I tried some examples with updating lines (using fwrite) but I see that its remove some characters from next line when I add some more characters such as ID4 and other strange characters in some trials) ). Any sample code?
2. Also later I would need to use locking to file, so only one should be able to read and write at one time. Any suggestions/links appreciated.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

For *appending* to a file you don't need a temporary file or anything. If you want to replace some characters with an *equal* amount of characters, you don't need a temporary file either.

***But*** if you want to do any other modification that changes the size of the contents you need some temporary buffer of some kind. Either a temporary file or an in-memory buffer.

Comment: Thanks for yoru answer, in my case, each line could have more or less characters after modification, I dont want to create a new file but yes, I tried to create a string with a new text and tried to do fwrite. something like this:    char str[30];
     strcpy(str,"local:IP:Port:1,3,5");
     rewind(f);
     int dom_len = strlen(sds_domain);
      int test1 = ftell(f); 
       printf("LINE NUMBER %d",test1);
     fwrite(str,1,strlen(str),f);
but it overwrites the text in the second line.